# postgresql correct encoding of characters

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have a row in a table defined as:

```
name character varying(255) NOT NULL
```

However,using the symfony framework, when i try to do a select I get the following error because in one row there is a "ü" character.

```
[37;41m  An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.name AS name_2, t0.description AS description_3, t0.type AS type_4, t0.parent_id AS parent_id_5 FROM postgres.categori
es t0  ←[39;49m
←[37;41m   WHERE t0.name = ? LIMIT 1' with params ["\x41\x6e\x7a\x81\x67\x65"]:
       ←[39;49m
←[37;41m  SQLSTATE[22021]: Character not in repertoire: 7 FEHLER:  ung├╝ltige Byte-Sequenz f├╝r Kodierung ┬╗UTF8┬½: 0x81
```

In doctrine the dbal config has charset set to UTF8.

How do i correct this? i.e. allow umlaut/ü characters

Comment: \X81 followed by \x67 is not valid UTF-8

Comment: name = Anzüge is what im selecting

Comment: for utf-8 shoiuld be `\xc3\xbc` instead of `\x81`

Comment: What does that mean for me though? Wrong database config? Wrong doctrine config?

Comment: What is your `client_encoding` set to?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe client_encoding is UNICODE. How can I change that to UTF8?

Comment: It is the same in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Can i set the client_encoding in doctrine?